# How do I save an updated CouchDB doc with Evently?

Tags: couchdb, save, couchapp, evently

I'm following [IBM's tutorial on CouchDB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-couchapp/section5.html) and ran into a problem saving *edited* documents. Saving a *new* doc works fine, and it looks like all my existing doc's values (retrieved via the [`openDoc`](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/) function) are valid, but the new values are simply not taking.

As I trace through the executing code, it looks like the new values are there:

[image]

However, after `saveDoc` **returns successfully** (strange!), the doc is not updated. If I log the updated doc, the logged object has no `_id` or `_rev` values, though you can clearly see they were present while saving (see first screenshot).

[image]

Is there some nuance of `saveDoc`, or perhaps [Evently](http://couchapp.org/page/evently-primer), that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `success` callback, you are not logging the *updated* document, your are logging the `newdoc` object from line 87 (minus it went through the `saveDoc` function, which apparently undefined `_id` and `_rev`, but that's ok).

The `success` callback can have an argument that is the response from the server. If you write :

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

you should see in the response a new `_rev` starting with `2-`.

If you really want to see the full doc once updated, just call `openDoc` from your `success` callback to get the updated version.

---

Other detail, when you say

> `saveDoc` **returns successfully**

I think you meant that the `success` callback is called, because `saveDoc` is asynchronous and should return instantly anyway.

Comment: What's odd is that I came back to this without modifying any code, and now it works. Maybe it was a caching issue - who knows? Thank you for the great tips though, especially the asynchronous bit. This will save me tons of time later!